# robert.hooke; or how to attach meta data to functions in Clojure

Tags: clojure, metadata, hook

I am using the [robert.hooke](https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke) Clojure library to try to add a behavior to any function in my application.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
(require '[robert.hooke :as hook])

(defn new-behavior
  [f & args]
  (let [id "test"]
    (println "The new behavior is to output the ID defined at the hook level: " id)
    (apply f args)))

(defn add-behavior!
  [id task-var]
  (hook/add-hook task-var new-behavior))
```

Then I would add a behavior this way:

```
(defn foo [] (println "foo test"))

(add-behavior! "foo-id" #'foo)
```

What I would like to be able to do here is to somehow change the meta data of the function of the `var` `task-var` in the `add-behavior!` function, and then to access the new meta data from the `new-behavior` function. I want to be able to do something like that (beware, this is not working obviously):

```
(defn new-behavior
  [f & args]
  (let [id (::behavior-id (meta f))]
    (println "The new behavior is to output the ID defined at the hook level: " id)
    (apply f args)))

(defn add-behavior!
  [id task-var]
  (alter-meta! task-var assoc-in [::behavior-id] id)
  (hook/add-hook task-var new-behavior))

(defn foo [] (println "foo test"))

(add-behavior! "foo-id" #'foo)
```

The current way doesn't work, since in `add-behavior!` it changes the meta-data of the `var` and what I am accessing in `new-behavior` is the meta-data of the function which is `nil`.

So, this lead to two questions:

1. how could I access the meta-data of the `var` associated to the `function` in `new-behavior`?
2. or, how could I change the meta-data of the `function` of the `var` in `add-behavior`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be acceptable to supply the var to `new-behavior` via `partial`?

```
(defn new-behavior
  [the-var f & args]
  (let [id (::behavior-id (meta the-var))]
    (println "The new behavior is to output the ID defined at the hook level: " id)
    (apply f args)))

(defn add-behavior!
  [id task-var]
  (alter-meta! task-var assoc-in [::behavior-id] id)
  (hook/add-hook task-var (partial new-behavior task-var)))

(defn foo [] (println "foo test"))

(add-behavior! "foo-id" #'foo)
```

Without knowing more about the problem you're trying to solve it's hard to tell if there's a better design here.

Comment: wonderful, yeah that would work since the arguments convention is only between `add-behavior!` and `new-behavior`. So I will certainly test that option. I was not aware of `partial` so it is a new tool in my toolbox. The idea is to be able to profile, introspect, log, etc. any function in my application without having to change the code's functions. So such hooks are perfect once you can daunt them :)

Comment: incidentally you can get the same functionality as `partial` via an anonymous function: `#(apply new-behavior task-var %&)`